# How to navigate from Activity B to specific fragment of Activity A?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

1. I have `Activity A`   which contains 4 `Fragments` in `ViewPager` with
   `BottomNavigationView` .
2. From 4th `Fragment` i navigate to `Activity B` .
3. In `Activity B`  there's one `Button` when clicked should navigate
   to `Fragment B` of `Activity A`   .

How to approach ? One point to be noted I don't want `Activity A` to be recreated as there's a lot API call's are being done on `Activity A`

P.S I have seen answers to similar questions but none are applicable as i am not dealing with Navigation View.

Comment: I think you have to make a setFragment method global then pass fragemnt values with `intent`

Comment: have you tried `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: I don't want to recreate Activity A

Comment: @Adi try with `startActivityForResult`. ADM is perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [**`startActivityForResult()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

1st Click from Fragment to ActivityB

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 102);
```

Button Click from ActivityB to Fragment

```
Intent backIntent = new Intent();
        backIntent.putExtra("data","test");
        setResult(RESULT_OK,backIntent);
        finish();
```

Then add **`onActivityResult ()`** Fragment section

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (data != null) {
            if (requestCode == 102) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.getStringExtra("data")))
                    {
                        //
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is about starting fragment in activity, not view pager

Comment: @AntonisRadz  `ViewPager with BottomNavigationView`

Comment: @AntonisRadz If `ViewPager` then user can use `setCurrentItem` else your logic

Comment: not applicable as , i want to load previous activity A which is in stack . Please read the edited description

Comment: @Adi check my logic

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest start `Activity` with the `Intent`, in intent add something like

`intent.putExtra(KEY_FRAGMENT, "YourFragmentName")`

and in other `Activity`:

```
  val fragmentName = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_FRAGMENT)
        if (fragmentName == "YourFragmentName") {
            // show fragment here
        }
```

Comment: not applicable as , i want to load previous activity A which is in stack . Please read the edited description

Comment: use this code combined with `startActivityForResult()` from A, and in B use `setResult()` and `finish()`. In B just get result in `onActivityResult()` and do navigation there.